# Transforming XML that has same name for all elements using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm working with an API that returns XML data, and the format is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<directory>
 <fieldset>
  <field id="displayName">Display name</field>
  <field id="firstName">First name</field>
  <field id="lastName">Last name</field>
 </fieldset>
 <employees>
  <employee id="40663">
   <field id="displayName">Scott Ackler</field>
   <field id="firstName">Scott</field>
   <field id="lastName">Ackler</field>
  </employee>
  <employee id="40556">
   <field id="displayName">Anna Adamson</field>
   <field id="firstName">Anna</field>
   <field id="lastName">Adamson</field>
   </employee>
 </employees>
</directory>
```

In order to work further, I need to transform the above XML into the following format:

```
<directory>
 <employees>
  <employee>
   <id>40663</id>
   <displayName>Scott Ackler</displayName>
   <firstName>Scott</firstName>
   <lastName>Ackler</lastName>
  </employee>
  <employee>
   <id>40556</id>
   <displayName>Anna Adamson</displayName>
   <firstName>Anna</firstName>
   <lastName>Adamson</lastName>
  </employee>
 </employees>
</directory>
```

I'm using XSLT to achieve this and so far I have the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<directory>
<employees>
<xsl:for-each select="/directory/employees/employee">
<employee>
<id>
<xsl:value-of   select="./@id"/>
</id>
<displayName>
<xsl:value-of   select="./field"/>
</displayName>
<firstName>
<xsl:value-of   select="./field"/>
</firstName>
<lastName>
<xsl:value-of   select="./field"/>
</lastName>
</employee>
</xsl:for-each>
</employees>
</directory>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above code has given me the following output:

```
<directory>
   <employees>
      <employee>
         <id>40663</id>
         <displayName>Scott Ackler</displayName>
         <firstName>Scott Ackler</firstName>
         <lastName>Scott Ackler</lastName>
      </employee>
      <employee>
         <id>40556</id>
         <displayName>Anna Adamson</displayName>
         <firstName>Anna Adamson</firstName>
         <lastName>Anna Adamson</lastName>
      </employee>
   </employees>
</directory>
```

The problem is evident. All nodes below 'employee' have the same name 'field', and so the XSLT code is giving me value of the first 'field' (displayName) and setting that value to all subsequent elements. The requirement is that the 'id' of each 'field' should be the element name and the value of each field id should be set to the element. I'm new to XSLT. Can someone please help me out this. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it simply like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="directory">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="employees"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="employees">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="employee"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="employee">
        <xsl:copy>
            <id><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></id>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="field"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="field">
        <xsl:element name="{@id}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nb9PtEd

Comment: This Worked! Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

For *displayName* use either `<xsl:value-of select="field[1]"/>` or `<xsl:value-of select="field[@id='displayName']"/>`.  And so on for the other fields.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following.

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="/directory">
        <directory>
            <employees>
                <xsl:for-each select="employees/employee">
                    <employee>
                        <id>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
                        </id>
                        <displayName>
                            <xsl:value-of select="field[@id='displayName']"/>
                        </displayName>
                        <firstName>
                            <xsl:value-of select="field[@id='firstName']"/>
                        </firstName>
                        <lastName>
                            <xsl:value-of select="field[@id='lastName']"/>
                        </lastName>
                    </employee>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </employees>
        </directory>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```